# Using custom api with Firebase cloud functions

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-functions

I am building an app that requires me to use Cloud Functions for device to device messaging. I have used cloud functions in the past but only with Firestore and Realtime Database. But my app doesn't use those platform. Am using a custom backend with custom API. So here's my question:

Is there a way I can use Cloud Functions to interact with my api for changes just like the way it works for Firestore? If yes, please share some helpful resources.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you're asking if you can call your custom Cloud Functions from within your Flutter app with a simple API, similar to how you call Cloud Firestore.

In that case the closest you can get is by creating a so-called [**Callable** Cloud Function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable), and then call that from your Flutter code by using the [`cloud-functions` plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/cloud_functions). Invoking your custom callable Cloud Function with this takes these steps:

> 1. `import 'package:cloud_functions/cloud_functions.dart';`
> 2. Getting an instance of the callable function:
>
>    ```
>    final HttpsCallable callable = CloudFunctions.instance.getHttpsCallable(
>        functionName: 'YOUR_CALLABLE_FUNCTION_NAME',
>    );
>    ```
> 3. Calling the function:
>
>    ```
>    dynamic resp = await callable.call();
>    ```
>
>    or
>
>    Calling the function with parameters:
>
>    ```
>    dynamic resp = await callable.call(<String, dynamic>{
>        'YOUR_PARAMETER_NAME': 'YOUR_PARAMETER_VALUE',
>    });
>    ```